# Counting the number of intersection points when joining $n$ points to each other.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, systems-of-equations, combinations, determinant

While solving another problem, I got the following problem;

On the $xy$-plane, there are $n$ known points $P_1(x_1,y_1),P_2(x_2,y_2),P_3(x_3,y_3),\dots,P_n(x_n,y_n)$.

Each point is connected to all $(n-1)$ points with straight lines.

Note: $P_1,P_2,P_3,\dots,P_n$ are intersection points.

Note: If more than two lines intersect at the same point, then this point must not be counted more than once.

> Considering the region: $\{ x_\text{min} \le x \le
> x_\text{max},y_\text{min} \le y \le y_\text{max} \}$, how to count the
>   number of the intersection points if we are given the coordinates of
>   $P_1,P_2,P_3,\dots,P_n$?

I have no idea except listing the points of intersection after solving every possible combination of equations of two lines. This is painful!

Expecting an elegant way, may be determinants or otherwise.

Any help would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but $P_1, P_2, \dots, P_n$ are _not_ the intersection points, right?  They are the points which you connect all-to-all, but the intersection points generated by these ${n \choose 2}$ segments are not named directly in the problem.

Comment: @Dude Can you please check my OP, I mentioned: "I have no idea except listing the points of intersection after solving every possible combination of equations of two lines. This is painful!"

Comment: @antkam $P_1,P_2,P_3,\dots,P_n$ are intersection points. See the region I mentioned is $\{ x_\text{min} \le x \le
x_\text{max},y_\text{min} \le y \le y_\text{max} \}$ (inclusion takes place). Consider as an example we have $4$ points as follows: $3$ points $P_1,P_2,P_3$ forming a triangle and the fourth point $P_4$ lies inside triangle $P_1P_2P_3$, join all points to each other. What can you say about $P_4$ then? Also $P1$ is an intersection point because line $P_1P_2$ and $P_1P_3$ intersect at $P_1$. Got my problem?

Comment: ah, I see, you mean the $P_j$'s count as intersection points, but of course there can be (lots more) other intersection points which are not $P_j$'s.  And you want the total, where the original $P_j$'s also count as part of the total.

Comment: @antkam Exactly.